# Catching an input error

Tags: c#, exception

I have this assignment for school where we have to use try and catch in order to ensure that the user doesn't input a negative number of donuts and data that is not an integer. I got the try/catch to work so that it asks for the number of donuts again when I enter a negative number, but when I enter a letter instead of a number for the number of donuts it comes up with the error message I created for it but doesn't give the option to enter the amount of donuts again. If someone could help me that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Here's what I got for my code:

```
using System;
public class CostofDonuts
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string lastName;
        int number_Of_Donuts;
        double Total_Cost, Final_Cost;


        try
        {

            // Get user to input their last name
            Console.Write("Enter customer's last name -> ");
            lastName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            //Get user to input amount of donuts purchased. Ensure that the integer inputted is positive.
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the amount of donuts purchased -> ");
                number_Of_Donuts = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (number_Of_Donuts < 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, number of donuts must be positive");
            } while (number_Of_Donuts <= 0);

            //Calculate cost of donuts
            if (number_Of_Donuts < 6)
                Total_Cost = number_Of_Donuts * 0.5;
            if (number_Of_Donuts <= 15)
                Total_Cost = number_Of_Donuts * 0.4;
            else
                Total_Cost = number_Of_Donuts * 0.3;

            //Calculate cost with tax
            if (number_Of_Donuts < 12)
                Final_Cost = (Total_Cost + 0.25) * 1.13;
            else
                Final_Cost = Total_Cost + 0.25;

            // Output final results
            Console.WriteLine("{0} bought {1} donuts which came to a total of {2:C}", lastName, number_Of_Donuts, Final_Cost);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input must be a positive integer");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input must be a positive integer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your try/catch needs to be inside a loop; right now if you throw an exception it skips out of your do/while loop and leaves the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `try / catch` inside of your loop in order to keep *continue*:

```
do
{
      Console.Write("Enter the amount of donuts purchased -> ");
      try
      {
           number_Of_Donuts = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
           Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, number of donuts must be positive");
           number_Of_Donuts = 0;
      }

} while (number_Of_Donuts <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `int.TryParse`

```
   do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the amount of donuts purchased -> ");
        if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number_Of_Donuts ) && number_Of_Donuts >= 0)
            break;
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, number of donuts must be positive");
    } while (number_Of_Donuts <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the amount of donuts purchased -> ");
            Int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number_Of_Donuts);
            if (number_Of_Donuts < 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, number of donuts must be positive");
        } while (number_Of_Donuts <= 0);
```